# Turning off colliding keyboard shortcuts in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, internationalization, shortcuts, customize-mode

While working in the table environment in ArcMap, I am not able to write several Polish characters without causing some action. Trying to write ą (AltGr+a) results in a Select All, ń (AltGr+n) ends up with flashing the select object, Ż (Shift+AltGr+Z) results with undoing last action, while writing Ś (Shift+AltGr+S) ends up with displaying Advance Table Sorting window.

How do I turn off those shortcuts?

I can't really find them in Customize Mode.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to remove the shortcut keys. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/customizing-the-ui/removing-a-shortcut-key.htm

Comment: As I said, I tried to find those in the Customize Mode (Customize Keyboard) but they don't seem to fit to any of the ones I found there.